# how to call function controller from html in Angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, button, controller, config

i want execute a hello world function into a controller (call from html with button click), but i cant call this and i do not know why it does not work because not any show a error.

html code:

```
<html ng-app="app">


   <div ng-controller="indexController">
      <button type="button"  ng-click="helloWorld()">action</button>
   </div>
```

and controller js:

```
(function () {
'use stritct';

angular
.module('app',[])
.controller('indexController', indexController);

indexController.inject = ['$rootScope','$scope'];

function indexController($rootScope,$scope) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.helloWorld = helloWorld;

    function helloWorld() {
        console.log('hello');
    }
}
})();
```

Comment: did you try onclick="helloWorld()" instead of ng-click="helloWorld()" in your html code?

Comment: Is that the directive ng click is typical of angular, and is the one that should use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access functions or data in the template from your controller, you must define the function or value on the `$scope` object. Anything you define on the `$scope` object you can use in the template.

Instead of `vm.helloWorld = helloWorld;` try `$scope.helloWorld = helloWorld;`

In the same way, you can access data from your controller and display it in the template.

```js
angular.module('app',[])
    .controller('indexController', indexController);

indexController.$inject = ['$rootScope','$scope'];

function indexController($rootScope,$scope) {
    $scope.helloWorld = function() {
        console.log('hello');
    }
    
    $scope.message = 'From the controller!';
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="indexController">
      <button type="button"  ng-click="helloWorld()">action</button>
      
      <p>{{ message }}</p>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can refer to the scope as a `this` object if you use a **Controller as Class** syntax, his code was fine, he just didn't declare his controller correctly

Comment: @AlekseySolovey Ah I see, I wasn’t aware of that syntax, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 3):

`ng-click="helloWorld()` will try to call `$scope.helloWorld()` function, that is undefined here.

*helloWorld* function is linked to your controller object, not to the Angular scope.

You have to set an alias of your controller, like `ng-controller="indexController as index"`, and you will can call your helloWorld function like this: `ng-click="index.helloWorld()"`.